# How do i get rid of annoying arrows in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]

I have these annoying yellow arrows that keep showing up in eclipse and folder names in project explorer turn black

What causes that and how do i get rid of it?

Comment: The arrows tell you that things inside have changed.  This is frequently useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the Git(?) team label provider:

You can find all the settings in ***Window > Preferences: Team > Git > Label Decoration***

Comment: I got rid of it with **Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Label Decoration** and deselect "Git"